# form is not inline with bootstrap

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap, haml

```
.container.homepage

= simple_form_for @search, :url => some_path, :method => :post do |form|

    %h1.heading Text
    %p.lead text

    %form.form-inline{role: "form"}
        %div.form-group
            %label.sr-only{for: "field1"} text
            %input.field1.form-control{placeholder: "question?", type: "text1"}
        %div.form-group
            %label.sr-only{for: "field2"} text
            %input.field2.form-control{placeholder: "some text", type: "text2"}
        %button.btn.btn-primary{type: "submit"} Search
```

I am trying to make the form to be inline using bootstrap, but for some reason it doesn't do that? the form stays vertical. Can someone help to identify the problem please as not sure what is wrong?

Comment: okay i fixed this problem, which was because I used simple_form. when I changed it to form_for, it all works fine. Can someone explain why it didn't work with simple_form?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to give an additional class to form element.
That is "form-inline"
But as your code its not working. You just need to use bootstrap columns.

for example

```
<form action="">
<div class="col-md-6">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="">
    </div></div> // sub col-md-6
    <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="">
    </div>
    /div> //sub col-md-6
</div> //row
</div> // Main col-md-6
    </form>
```

Thankss :)